Is there any module other than tabula-py and camelot to extract tables from native pdfs?
Was using tabula-py for extracting tabular information and then storing it in .csv files however it fails to understand the structure of the tableScreenshot of pdf using as a dataset Real structure of table
Extracted data using tabula Extracted structure using tabula module is not matching with the real structure.
Also if you look at the Screenshot of pdf you will find college name and course name which were outside the structure and it was extracted and stored in a .csv file easily but was using PyPDF2.
I want to create a .csv file with College name, Course name, GOPENS cutoff,....... for all cateogries

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sample inputs and expected outputs, plus MWE code, would help us move faster! :) FWIW, tabula works well for me. Maybe csv's not appropriate for you, who knows :)
